# finding a corrupted part from the parts of a split archive

Tags: rar, winrar

I have 7 files with extensions like xyz.rar.001 - xyz.rar.007 clearly they are parts of a single file. I have all the 7 parts. I join them using a file joiner into a single file xyz.rar and try to unrar them with WINRAR , it says that archive is corrupted It is clear that 1 or 2 parts are corrupted. IS THERE ANY WAY TO FIND THEM ? Please help I don't want to re download all of them NOTE- winrar can detect a corrupt part if the parts were splitted using winrar (with extensions like part1.rar , part2.rar etc. ) but not if they are named as rar.001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 7-zip to extract them directly (**don't use a file joiner**) 
Unlike Winrar , 7-zip can handle those .001 type files.If one of the archive is corrupt it will surely mention the part ( " crc failed in part x " ) but this will occur only if the data is damaged during downloading .
 If this is not the case you can only solve this with the help of a recovery record. Simplest way is ask the person who uploaded the files to give you each file's **checksum**then compare each of your own file's checksum with it the file with a different checksum is corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

WinRAR can extract those .001, .002, ... files just as well as part1.rar, part2.rar, ...
Simply open up the .001 with WinRAR. What I've done on my PC is set the .001 extension to automatically open up with WinRAR - that way I can right-click on it in the explorer and see all the regular WinRAR options.
Check this link if you need some more info http://www.binaries4all.com/001/winrar.php.

Comment: I mentioned earlier that all splitted files joined successfully into one archive but the archive is corrupted. since I download all the parts at different times so 1 or 2 may be corrupted I just want to figure out WHICH ONE IS CORRUPT Note-on using winrar on .001 file it says "Unexpected end of archive" (does it mean last part is corrupt ?)